# Subtract lists' elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I have 2 lists, that have the following form:

```
List1 = {{0.0, val10}, {0.1, val11}, {0.2, val12},...}
List2 = {{0.0, val20}, {0.1, val21}, {0.2, val22},...}
```

I would like to make a normalized `ListDiff` defined in such a way that it has the form:

```
ListDiff = {{0.0, (val10 - val20)/val10}, {0.1, (val11 - val21)/val11}, {0.2, (val12 - val22)/val12},...}
```

Is there any procedure in Mathematica to perform this operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ListDiff = Transpose[{
   List1[[All, 1]],
   Subtract[1., List2[[All, 2]]/List1[[All, 2]]]
   }]
```

is slightly faster than Bob Hanlon's second proposal...

Answer (score 8):

Another approach,

```
List1 = {{0.0, val10}, {0.1, val11}, {0.2, val12}};
List2 = {{0.0, val20}, {0.1, val21}, {0.2, val22}};

{#[[1, 1]], (#[[1, 2]] - #[[2, 2]])/#[[1, 2]]} & /@ 
 Transpose[{List1, List2}]

(* {{0., (val10 - val20)/val10}, {0.1, (val11 - val21)/val11}, {0.2, (
  val12 - val22)/val12}} *)
```

Or

```
Transpose@{List1[[All, 1]], (List1[[All, 2]] - List2[[All, 2]])/
   List1[[All, 2]]}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way:

```
ListDiff = List1;
ListDiff[[All, 2]] -= List2[[All, 2]];
ListDiff[[All, 2]] /= List1[[All, 2]];

ListDiff
```

> {{0., (val10 - val20)/val10}, {0.1, (val11 - val21)/val11}, {0.2, (val12 - val22)/val12}}

Comment: Looks nice, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You might consider using [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association) objects instead. For example:

```
List1 = {{0.0, val10}, {0.1, val11}, {0.2, val12}};
List2 = {{0.0, val20}, {0.1, val21}, {0.2, val22}};

assoc1 = Association[Rule @@@ List1]
assoc2 = Association[Rule @@@ List2]
```

> <|0. -> val10, 0.1 -> val11, 0.2 -> val12|>
>
> <|0. -> val20, 0.1 -> val21, 0.2 -> val22|>

Arithmetic with associations acts on the values. So:

```
(assoc1 - assoc2)/assoc1
```

> <|0. -> (val10 - val20)/val10, 0.1 -> (val11 - val21)/val11, 
>    0.2 -> (val12 - val22)/val12|>

Answer (score 4):

```
f1 = {#[[1, 1]], (#2 - #1)/#1 & @@ #[[All, 2]]} & /@ GatherBy[Join[##], First] &;
f2 = {#[[1, 1]], (#2 - #1)/#1 & @@ #[[All, 2]]} & /@ SplitBy[Sort@Join[##], First] &;

f1[List1, List2]
```

> {{0., (-val10 + val20)/val10}, {0.1, (-val11 + val21)/ val11}, {0.2, (-val12 + val22)/val12}}

```
f1[List1, List2] == f2[List1, List2]
```

> True

Answer (score 4):

You can use $\texttt{Cases}$ and pattern-matching:

```
Cases[
  Transpose[{List1, List2}],
  {{n_, v1_}, {n_, v2_}} :> {n, (v2 - v1)/v1}
]
```

Comment: Thanks for this!

Answer (score 3):

You have a low reputation, so I'm assuming you are fairly new to *Mathematica*.  As such, here is an inelegant (but easily understood) approach:

```
Table[
   {List1[[i, 1]], (List1[[i, 2]] - List2[[i, 2]])/List1[[i, 2]]}, 
  {i, Length[List1]}]
```

And a word of advice:  Never use upper-case to start the name of a variable, as it may conflict with an internal function in Mathematica.  This is especially concerning if your variable is List1--so close to the function `List`.  And ListDiff might be similar to the 30 or so internal functions that begin with "List".

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought I would have to write a cycle. Never get used to Tables... And, I'm assuming you forgot division symbol.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html).

```
MapThread[
 {First[#1], First[1 - Rest[#2] / Rest[#1]]}&, {List1, List2}]
```

Evaluating the code above, returns

> ```
> { { 0. , 1 - val20/val10 }, 
>   { 0.1, 1 - val21/val11 },
>   { 0.2, 1 - val22/val12 } }
> ```

(input lists are concatenated so as to allow evaluation).

`MapThread` applies a function on tuples, taken in a successive manner from the input lists (see code above).

The first tuple, contains the first element from every input list, the second tuple consists of the second element in each input list and so on.

Since, in this example, we are dealing with only *two* input lists (`List1` and `List2`), the function that is applied on successive input tuples, receives *two* arguments ie `#1` and `#2`.

These, are numbered slots  (see [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html)). They stand for the successive inputs, fed into the function argument of `MapThread`.

In this particular case we are dealing with, both of them are lists, with *two* entries eg in the case of the first tuple, `#1` stands for `{0.0, val10}` and `#2` stands for `{0.0, val20}`.

Continuing with the example of the first input tuple, evaluating `First[#1]` returns `0.` (this is the `First` item in `{0.0, val10}`) while `Rest[#1]` returns `{val01}` (the second entry of `{0.0,val10}`-notice the braces).

Similarly, `Rest[#2]` returns `{val20}` (because `#2` is equal to `{0.0, val20}`) and if we combine all the parts of the function together we get `{0.,1-val20/val10}`.

The rest of the output is constructed along similar lines.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 2):

**Using `Merge`:**

```
alist = {{0.0, val10}, {0.1, val11}, {0.2, val12}};
blist = {{0.0, val20}, {0.1, val21}, {0.2, val22}};

Merge[{Rule @@@ alist, 
     Rule @@@ blist}, (First@# - Last@#)/(First@#) &] // Normal // 
  ReplaceAll[Rule -> List] // Column
```

---

*Result:*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
l1 = {{0.0, val10}, {0.1, val11}, {0.2, val12}};
l2 = {{0.0, val20}, {0.1, val21}, {0.2, val22}};
```

---

Using `Thread` and `MapApply`:

```
{#1[[1]], 1 - #2[[2]]/#1[[2]]} & @@@ Thread[{l1, l2}]
```

*Result*:

[image]

Or using `GroupBy`:

```
l3 = Catenate[{l1, l2}];

gby = GroupBy[l3, #[[1]] &, 1 - #2/#3 & @@ Union@## & @@ Transpose@# &]

Thread[{Keys@#, Values@#}] &@gby
```

*Result*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {{0.0, val10}, {0.1, val11}, {0.2, val12}};
b = {{0.0, val20}, {0.1, val21}, {0.2, val22}};
```

Using `MapApply` (new in 13.1)

```
{c, d} = Association @* MapApply[Rule] /@ {a, b};
```

Display as `Dataset`

```
(c - d) / c // Dataset
```

[image]

Convert to `List`

```
(c - d) / c // KeyValueMap[List] // TableForm
```

[image]

If we want to change `a` and `b` inline, we can use `ApplyTo` (new in
12.2)

```
{a, b} //= Map[Association @* MapApply[Rule]];

(a - b) / a // Dataset
```

(* output like above *)